# Access an element not generated by an xsd?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xsd, linq-to-xml

I do not have the xsd files, but I had currently I have a auto-generated class Customer that has the field Extensions, so I can access something like:

```
<Customer>
   <Extensions/>
</Customer>
```

I need to be able to access something like:

```
<Customer>
   <Extensions>
      <Room>12345</Room>
   </Extensions>
</Customer>
```

The XML will have the following, I just need to get the Room value from the xml.  Currently, all I can do is:

```
Customer.Extensions;
```

The Room element does not exist in the auto-generated code, but it will exist in the incoming XML request.

Answer (score 0):

I actually was able to do:

```
Dim elem as XmlElement  = Custoemr.Extensions.Any().ElementAt(0)
Dim room As elem.InnerText
```

Don't know if there are any caveats to this.  If there are, can someone point it out?